# Compare revisions (custom fields) in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress site (v3.9.2) where contributors edit posts. However the data is fed in by contributors as custom fields. Then in the pending revision page the modified custom fields are not displayed, just the modified title and the modified content.

That means even if my contributor has edited the custom fields and submitted the post for revision I can't see them in the pending revision while comparing them.

I've tried with "Custom Field Revision" plugin but it seems that it doesn't work in last versions of WordPress. Do you know any other plugin for comparing custom fields as revision? Or any other solution?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you but I can tell you that this is something that WordPress is thinking very deeply about. [This ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/20564) has been around for 2 years and has been fairly active in that time. That ticket also includes some code that you might be able to utilize for your client.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display custom fields revision with Revisionary plugin (or similar) in WordPress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25527606/how-to-display-custom-fields-revision-with-revisionary-plugin-or-similar-in-wo)